# ASP.NET Core, <br> text on specific length

Tags: c#, razor-pages

```
<div class="input-container">
    <p>@review.review</p>
</div>
```

How can I break the text at a specific place?

Comment: You want to do this with CSS. It's called overflow-wrap. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Text/Wrapping_Text#breaking_long_words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways! the easiest way is by just using word-break in css.
you can then adjust the amount of words by adjusting the width.

```
.input-container > p {
    word-break: break-word;
    width: 125px
}
```

i assume you want to use c# so you could give regex a try

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(\b.{1,25})(?:\s+|$)";
        string substitution = @"";
        string input = @"Please write a program that breaks this text into small chucks. Each chunk should have a maximum length of 25 ";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```